# Converting an array of objects to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
let arr = [
  { id: 1, day: 3, dimension: 2 },
  { id: 2, day: 5, dimension: 2 },
  { id: 3, day: 2, dimension: 1 },
  { id: 4, day: 0, dimension: 1 },
  { id: 5, day: 0, dimension: 0 }
];
```

in which `day` it is the day of the week (0 - Monday, 1 - Tuesday etc)

I need to convert an array to another array by parameter `dimension`, so as to get such an array:

```
let newArrray = [
  {
    dimension: 0,
    week: [
      { key: 0, value: 'M', active: true },
      { key: 1, value: 'T', active: false },
      { key: 2, value: 'W', active: false },
      { key: 3, value: 'T', active: false },
      { key: 4, value: 'F', active: false },
      { key: 5, value: 'S', active: false },
      { key: 6, value: 'S', active: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    dimension: 1,
    week: [
      { key: 0, value: 'M', active: true },
      { key: 1, value: 'T', active: false },
      { key: 2, value: 'W', active: true },
      { key: 3, value: 'T', active: false },
      { key: 4, value: 'F', active: false },
      { key: 5, value: 'S', active: false },
      { key: 6, value: 'S', active: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    dimension: 2,
    week: [
      { key: 0, value: 'M', active: false },
      { key: 1, value: 'T', active: false },
      { key: 2, value: 'W', active: false },
      { key: 3, value: 'T', active: true },
      { key: 4, value: 'F', active: false },
      { key: 5, value: 'S', active: true },
      { key: 6, value: 'S', active: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

I choose unique values `dimension`, create an empty array and fill it with an array with the days of the week:

```
let dimensionArray = [];
function checkDimension(index) {
  if (indexArray.indexOf(index) === -1) {
    dimensionArray.push(index);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
let uniqueDimensions = this.arr.filter((item) => checkDimension(item.dimension));

daysOfWeek = [
    { key: 0, value: 'M', active: false },
    { key: 1, value: 'T', active: false },
    { key: 2, value: 'W', active: false },
    { key: 3, value: 'T', active: false },
    { key: 4, value: 'F', active: false },
    { key: 5, value: 'S', active: false },
    { key: 6, value: 'S', active: false }
  ];
resultArray = [];

uniqueDimensions.forEach(uniq => {
  this.resultArray.push({
    dimension: uniq.dimension,
    week: this.daysOfWeek
  });
});

this.arr.forEach(item => {
  let dim = this.resultArray.find(res => res.dimension === item.dimension);
  dim.week.find(day => day.key === item.day).active = true;
});
```

But in the end I get an array in which the days of the week are all selected as `true`.
Any solutions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the maximum dimension and create all the subarray objects at once, in dimension order. That'll make the process much easier, now that you don't have to dynamically create anything later. Then all you need to do is iterate over each element of the original array and use the `day` and `dimension` as index lookups to identify which subobject to change.

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1, day: 3, dimension: 2 },
  { id: 2, day: 5, dimension: 2 },
  { id: 3, day: 2, dimension: 1 },
  { id: 4, day: 0, dimension: 1 },
  { id: 5, day: 0, dimension: 0 }
];
const maxDimension = Math.max(...input.map(obj => obj.dimension));
const dayAbbrevs = 'MTWTFSS';
const output = Array.from(
  { length: maxDimension + 1 },
  (_, i) => ({
    dimension: i,
    week: Array.from(
      { length: 7 },
      (_, j) => ({ key: j, value: dayAbbrevs[j], active: false })
    )
  })
);
for (const { day, dimension } of input) {
  output[dimension].week[day].active = true;
}
console.log(output);
```

The `Array.from`s and the `dayAbbrevs` above are just the approaches I prefer for [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code, but it's not essential - however you want to create the full structure initially, the problem will be much easier to solve by separating that out from the `active` changes.

Comment: Approximately such scheme the decision I also considered. The solution was slightly modified by me, there is a case when `dimension ` in `const input` may be skipped. For example, not 0, 1, 2 as in the example, but 0, 1, 3, 5. In any case, the answer is accepted.